# How to do a feature fusion of text and other features(such as time, company name)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

In my limited experience with NLP, I now have a problem with classification, that is, I use word embedding to make the text of each sample into a dimension of 200x300, and then send it to TextCNN for classification. At the same time, there are some other features in hand, such as which company this data comes from, the year of the data, etc., I also want to participate these features in the classification learning, then I face the question, do I vectorize these features and merge them into the vector set after word embedding processing? Or do you classify these features separately, and then fuse the results of the two classifiers?

If these feature vectors are quantized, how many dimensions should they be processed into vectors, and then how can they be combined with text vectors?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I haven't tried it